# Prove that Tr$[x,y]^m=0$ for $m \ge 1$

Tags: lie-algebras

$V$ is a complex vector space and $x,y \in gl(V)$ are linear maps such that $[x,y]$ commutes with both $x$ and $y$. Let $z=[x,y]$. Show that tr$z^m=0$ for all $m\ge 1$.

I have thought about this question for a long time, but I don't know how to use the condition that $z$ commutes with $x$, $y$. Can somebody give me some hints? Thank you.By the way, we haven't learnt Engel's Theorem or Lie's Thm at this point, so I cannot use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have$\def\tr{\mathop{\rm tr}}$
\begin{align*}
  \tr([x,y]^{m}) &= \tr\bigl((xy-yx)[x,y]^{m-1}\bigr)\\
          &= \tr(xy[x,y]^{m-1}) - \tr(y[x,y]^{m-1}x) & \text{as $x[x,y]^{m-1}=[x,y]^{m-1} x$}\\
          &= \tr(xy[x,y]^{m-1}) - \tr(xy[x,y]^{m-1}) & \text{property of the trace}\\
          &= 0
\end{align*}

Comment: why $tr(y[x,y]^{m-1}x)=tr(xy[x,y]^{m-1})?$

Comment: Apply $\tr(ab) = \tr(ba)$ to $a = y[x,y]^{m-1}$ and $b=x$

Comment: why is $x[x,y]^{m-1}=[x, y]^{m-1}x$?